# Setting timezone in countdown

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, countdown

I have codes like the one below and I want to set the timezone for it. May I know how can I do that?

Codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var year = new Date();

    year = new Date(year.getFullYear(), 11 - 1, 20);

    $('#dvCountDown').countdown({
      until: new Date('2013-02-08'),
      format: 'HMS',
      onExpiry: liftOff
    });

    $('#CountdownbyValue').countdown({
      until: '0h +0m +8s',
      format: 'HMS',onExpiry: liftOff
    });

    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());

    //Time is up!
    function liftOff() { 
      alert('Time is up!'); 
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Does that `coundown` plugin output UTC properly or which methods does it use? Could you link to its docs/source?

Comment: The countdown plugin is not important for this question IMHO - you get a Date object, and what he seems to be asking for is how to make the Date object constructor take the timezone into consideration - a pure Javascript question, independent of 3rd party code. However, using Google finds PLENTY of answers, that's why I didn't even bother... sorry guys, but some questions have been answered A LOT already.

Comment: @Mörre: Oh, right. I had expected the plugin to output the date, but likely it uses the difference value only. Still, my answer is useful then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
var year = new Date();
year.setUTCMonth(11 - 1);
year.setUTCDay(20);
year.setUTCHour( /* your timezone offset */ );
year.setUTCMinutes( /* your timezone offset */ );
year.setUTCSeconds(0);

$('#dvCountDown').countdown({
  until: new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 2-1, 08)),
  format: 'HMS',
  onExpiry: liftOff
});
```